Kubuntu 24.04.1 graphics mode not starting since kernel 6.8.0-45
I have an hp pavilion which runs fine under kubuntu 24.04.1 with kernel 6.8.0-40. Unfortunately, later kernels 6.8.0-45 and 6.8.0-47 fail to start in graphics mode. It just takes forever, until I revert to command line and reboot to the latest working kernel.
I'd appreciate any help to troubleshoot the problem. Thanks.
Gandalf
UPDATE 1: When I type startx, here is what I get:
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux titi 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep  27 21:40:26 UTC 2024 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic root=UUID=c79a0a0f-9650-4412-a13e-7c3bb8897750 ro quiet splash nomodeset vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.12-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Oct 23 21:11:03 2024
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
vesa: refusing to run, Framebuffer or dri device present
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error

UPDATE 2: I removed the nvidia 470 drivers and managed to boot kernel 6.8.0-47 in graphics mode, but it seems that my wifi card is no longer recognized. So it looks like several drivers are messed up, the graphics adapter and the wifi adapter, and maybe more.

What happens when you type "startx" or "xinit"? Any error messages, please post them here.

edited my post with the output of startx

Well, the startx output gives you info about what went wrong and a link :). On top of that, you can have a look at the config file (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d) and check that framebuffer settings. "cd /usr/share/X11", "sudo cp xorg.conf.d rem_xorg.conf.d" and "sudo nano xorg.conf.d".

Alain, I don't understand why several driver problems (wifi, nvidia) are occurring with kernel 6.8.0-47 while eveything is fine with kernel 6.8.0-40. Don't the two kernels use the same config files (/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d)?
